# False proof? If $f: G \rightarrow H$ homomorphism, and $H$ abelian, then $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $f: G \rightarrow H$ be homomorphism, and $H$ is abelian.

So $G \big/ \ker f \cong \operatorname{im}f$. Since $\operatorname{im}f$ is abelian, so is $G \big/ \ker f$. So for every $g_1,g_2 \in G$: $g_1\ker f\cdot g_2\ker f=g_2\ker f \cdot g_1\ker f \Rightarrow g_1g_2\ker f=g_2g_1\ker f$, hence $g_1g_2=g_2g_1$, so $G$ is abelian.

Comment: For an easy counterexample take any group $G$ and look at the trivial homomorphism to the trivial group (which is trivially abelian).  For a more interesting example, think of the sign homormorphism $\mathop{sgn}:S_n \to \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: You can only make your final conclusion if $\text{ker}(f) = \{ e \}$.  Thus, what you have proven is that if $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a one-to-one homomorphism and $H$ is an abelian group, then $G$ is abelian group.  Or in other words, a subgroup of an abelian group is abelian.  (Also, +1 for writing out your thought process.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality $g_1 g_2 \ker f = g_2 g_1 \ker f$ doesn't imply that $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$; in fact, all it implies is that

$$g_1 g_2 (g_2 g_1)^{-1} \in \ker f$$

Comment: Combining this with Ryan Sullivant's comment, suppose $f: G \rightarrow H$ is the trivial homomorphism from a group $G$ to the trivial one-element group $H$, then $\text{ker}(f) = G$, so $g_1 g_2 \text{ker}(f) = g_2 g_1 \text{ker}(f)$ only tells you that $g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1} \in G$, which is not new information at all!

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Indeed; furthermore, since $H$ is abelian, we have $$f(g_1 g_2 (g_2 g_1)^{-1}) = f(g_1) f(g_2) f(g_1)^{-1} f(g_2)^{-1} = e_H$$ so this doesn't provide anything additional in *any* case.

Answer (score 2):

Take any nonabelian group $G$ and $H$ the trivial group. It does imply, however, that $G$ admits an abelian quotient. If $H$ is nontrivial, [this is relevant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) In fact, one can define solvability in terms of the following "circular" way:

A group $G$ is solvable if there exists a proper subgroup $H$ such that

$(\rm i)$ $G/H$ is abelian, or

$(\rm ii)$ $G/H$ is solvable.